# PowerShell and space in expression

Tags: powershell, select, import-csv

I have a field in a CSV that is First Name. However, I want to rename that to Name.

I have the following code below. However, I am not sure how to handle that space between the `t` and `N`.

I've tried using quotes and some other tricks but so far none have worked.
What do I need to do to get the values?

```
Import-Csv .\Downloads\addata.csv | Select @{n="Name";e={$_.First Name}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access variables with a space using single quotes, e. g. `$_.'First Name'`.

However, you probably want to keep the existing columns so you might use the `Get-Content` cmdlet to retrieve the content and use a simple regex to replace the column within the first line:

```
$content = Get-Content '.\Downloads\addata.csv'
$content[0] = $content[0] -replace 'First Name', 'Name'
$content | Set-Content '.\Downloads\addata.csv'
```

**Attention:** You may want to specify the *encoding* within the `Set-Content` cmdlet.